# unable to resolve package in react native app

Tags: react-native

I have removed some packages in my react native.Removed the package import from all files .After I have done that my app can't start even I clear the cache using below procedure .

rm -rf node_modules # With Yarn workspaces, you may need to
# delete node_modules in each workspace
yarn cache clean
yarn
watchman watch-del-all
rm -fr $TMPDIR/haste-map-*
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-cache
expo start --clear

this my error

Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve module cloudinary-react from /Users//Desktop/react-native-with-firebase-course/my-test-project/screens/Home.js: cloudinary-react could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
   7 | import {Card, Button}  from  'react-native-paper';
   8 | import firebase from '../database/firebaseDb';

> 9 | import {Image as Image1, Transformation, Placeholder} from 'cloudinary-react'
> |                                                             ^
> 10 |
> 11 | import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
> 12 |
> Failed building JavaScript bundle.
> Unable to resolve module cloudinary-react from /Users//Desktop/react-native-with-firebase-course/my-test-project/screens/Home.js: cloudinary-react could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
   7 | import {Card, Button}  from  'react-native-paper';
   8 | import firebase from '../database/firebaseDb';

> 9 | import {Image as Image1, Transformation, Placeholder} from 'cloudinary-react'
> |                                                             ^
> 10 |
> 11 | import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
> 12 |

Comment: Double check you're not importing anything from cloudinary-react, specifically it looks like in your screens/Home.js file.

Comment: I checked,import is not there anymore ,it was removed ,it seems this file is caching somewhere with old import ,I can't figure out where

Comment: Have you tried deleting your yarn.lock file and then running yarn install again? Seems to be missing from your steps above.

Comment: I have just done that and this fix my issue,thanks a lot